# Converting a color image to grayscale is showing black image in java

Tags: java, bufferedimage, grayscale

I am trying to convert an image to gray scale image using Java. The problem here is, when I am trying to save that image after converting into gray scale it is showing a black image. I am little unaware of this image conversions. I would like to know why it is not working, and your answers will help me in my project. Thank you.

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(fileContent);
File outputFile = new File(date1);
ImageIO.write(image1, "png", outputFile);
```

(This is the color image obtained from html page, and it is working properly. And when I am trying to display/save this image, color image is visible. But the problem arises when the below code is used to convert color image to gray scale image.)

```
     BufferedImage image1 = new BufferedImage(width, height,BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);  
     Graphics graphics = image1.getGraphics();  
     graphics.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);  
     graphics.dispose();

     File outputFile = new File(date1);
     ImageIO.write(image1, "png", outputFile);
```

Comment: Just wondering: does your code work if you don't include the conversion? Meaning: I would first try to get the flow to show me the original picture; when that works you can think about pulling in your conversion.

Comment: Initially when I try to display/ save color image I can see the image, after conversion it is showing black image instead of gray scale image.

Comment: Can you try to display the image, in a `JFrame` or similar, to see if the problem is the conversion or the saving of the grayscale image? Does it matter if you use a different output file format, like BMP or JPEG?

Comment: JPEG file format is not preferred when we try image encryptions. Thats why I am using png images.

Comment: Well I don't think problem is near the saving part of the image because I have tried to save color image as well to see the output and I can see the image in that location.

Comment: I'm not saying you should use it in the final code, just a as a way of debugging *where* the problem arises. Anyway, try BMP then. Saving a color image is not the same, so it's worth a try, even if a long shot.

Comment: Ok, I will try that and let you know.

Comment: Your code works fine for me... Both drawing into a gray scale image, and using `ColorConvertOp` as suggested by @copeg. Maybe the problem is your input image or the specific Java version you are on?

Comment: Thank you. Problem is with the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are color space conversion issues. You can manually convert each pixel of the output image to grayscale and set the pixels of the output image this way:

```
int gray = red * 0.299 + green * 0.587 + blue * 0.114
```

or use the ColorConvertOp class to do the conversion for you:

```
BufferedImage in = ImageIO.read(inputFile);
BufferedImage out = new BufferedImage(in.getWidth(), in.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
ColorConvertOp op = new ColorConvertOp(in.getColorModel().getColorSpace(), ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY),  null);
op.filter(in, out);
ImageIO.write(out, "png", outputFile);
```

Comment: ColorConvertOp is also showing black image as the output.

Comment: Does your image have transparency?

Comment: Transparency means? Sorry I am unaware of this image processing terms.

Comment: Presuming the original image is of type INT_ARGB (or contains 'A' in the type), the 'A' stands for alpha, which allows for colors in the other channels to be transparent. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing

Comment: I edited my answer above - changing the destination image type - to allow for transparency in the destination image.

Comment: Sorry, it is showing black image only. I don't know where it went wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73692/discussion-between-copeg-and-user3364490).

Comment: The values ` int gray = red * 0.299 + green * 0.587 + blue * 0.114 ` are incorrect, they related to the obsolete NTSC broadcast system. The current default standard is sRGB, BUT ALSO you need to linearize (remove gamma) **first** ... here is a one line:

```JS      //ANDY'S DOWN AND DIRTY GRAYSCALE™
gray=((Rs/255.0)**2.2*0.2126+(Gs/255.0)**2.2*0.7152+(Bs/255.0)**2.2*0.0722)**0.4545*255; 
```